# Testing Properties on the Yielded Context of an Ember Component

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

There are times where I'm working on components that need to yield out data transfer objects (DTO's) for the sake of dividing concerns. For example, if I have some kind of UI component that I want to be reused in multiple contexts. I would extract this presentational component into something non-async leaving a wrapper that handles an async call when it's needed. The async component then would yield out the data of the call. An example usage would be:

```
{{#call-ajax as |data|}}
  {{presentation-component title=data.title}}
{{/call-ajax}}
```

Now, for a test, I don't want to have to use the `presentation-component` in tests for the `call-ajax` component but I need some way of making assertions about the result of the ajax call yielded as `data`.

My initial thought is some kind of component/helper made available only to tests that exposes an API for checking usages and what they are called with. Perhaps having something like this in the test:

```
this.render(hbs`
  {{#call-ajax as |data|}}
    {{test-inspector data}}
  {{/call-ajax}}
`);
```

Although, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Are there any suggestions on how I can test the `data` object without printing all primitive fields from it and doing DOM lookups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via registering a helper with the registry available to the `this` context on integration tests in Ember.js and passing it the information as arguments over some mechanism to store those for later inspection.

I'm using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) through [ember-sinon](https://github.com/csantero/ember-sinon) in the example below but it can be done in a more vanilla way if desired:

```
const stub = sinon.stub();
const helper = Ember.Helper.helper(stub);
this.register('helper:test-inspector', helper);

this.render(hbs`
  {{#call-ajax as |data|}}
    {{test-inspector data}}
  {{/call-ajax}}
`);

assert.deepEqual(stub.getCall(0).args[0][0], expectedData);
```